# Induced SES on Exterior Powers exercise in Huybrechts

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, exterior-algebra, line-bundles

I'm trying to do exercise 2.2.2 in Huybrecths's *Complex Geometry: An Introduction*. It reads:

**2.2.2** Show that any short exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles $0\to L\to E\to F\to 0$, where $L$ is a line bundle, induces a short exact sequence of the form $$0\to L\otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^{i-1} F \to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i}E\to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i} F\to 0.$$

I think my main struggle is how to work with exterior powers (and the other constructions) of vector bundles. I know that, for example, $\bigwedge\nolimits^i E$ has (canonically, whatever that means) fiber $\bigwedge\nolimits^i E(x)$ over $x$ but I'm having a hard time then thinking what $E$ itself is (i.e. how these fiber come together in a smooth way).

I figure that maybe it suffices to work with fibers though, i.e. to show that the induced $$0\to L(x) \otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^{i-1} F(x) \to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i}E(x)\to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i} F(x)\to 0$$ is exact for all $x$. Would this be enough and if so, why is it enough?

Anyway, if it is enough, here is my attempt. Denote the initial maps by $\phi:L\to E$ and $\psi:E\to F$. The map $\bigwedge\nolimits^{i} E(x) \to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i} F(x)$ is defined on basis elements by $s_1\wedge \cdots \wedge s_i \mapsto \psi_x(s_1)\wedge \cdots \wedge \psi_x(s_i).$

Now we want a map $L(x)\otimes \to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i-1}F(x)\to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i} E(x)$. Now $L(x)$ is $1$-dimensional as $L$ is a line-bundle so say $L(x)$ is spanned by $v$. Then we can map $v$ to $E(x)$ via $\phi_x$. It remains to map an element of the form $t_1\wedge \cdots \wedge t_{i-1}$ for $t_i\in F(x)$. Now as the map $E(x)\mapsto F(x)$ is surjective, there exists $e_j\in E(x)$ with $\psi_x(e_j)=t_j$. Now I would like to map $t_1\wedge \cdots \wedge t_{i-1}$ to $e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i-1}$ but this seems to involve many choices and I'm not sure it's correct. I do know that if $\psi_x(e_j')=t_j$ too then $e_j, e_j'$ differ by a multiple of $\varphi_x(v)$ because of the exactness of the initial sequence but I'm not sure how to use this.

So could someone please clarify some things here, in particular: (1) why is it enough to work on the fibers (and if it's not enough, how would one approach this problem) and (2) how to define that last map properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I advise you to crosspost this very specialized question on https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: For your two questions see Exercise 1.2, Chapter II of Hartshorne's textbook. The map you define for question (2) is well-defined using the short exact sequence for the $(i-1)$-exterior powers.

Comment: I think the problem is subtle one. Exercise 1.2, Chapter II of Hartshorne's book says then if there exist already global maps between vector bundles, then a lot of properties (injectivity, surjectivity, exactness of sequences) can be checked locally on fibers. But if I understand the OP's problem correctly then the point is how to construct the sequence $0\to L\otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^{i-1} F \to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i}E\to \bigwedge\nolimits^{i} F\to 0$ globally. note that locally after appropriate choice of basis we can always construct such map but the question is if after making

Comment: all the choices it finally patches together to a global sequence. It's too late and I'm tired to assemble assembe everything together, but the problem reminds me on the methods used in Hartshorne's book in Ex. 5.16 of same chapter. The idea was to use filtrations. I'm not sure if it could work here but maybe you can find filtrations for every object in the sequence such that you can then construct globaly a sequence between quotients of abutting filration members...